In Exchange 365, how to change the visibility of events in shared calendars?
In Exchange 365, the default for shared  calendars (also for resources, rooms) is that only the availability is shown to the users. I need users see the title and the creator of the events by default.

Unfortunately, there is GUI in the administration portal for this setting. You can use instead Powershell. Execute the following lines for that. It can be on any system, client or server. You can even create a temporary Windows sandbox to avoid permanent changes, since some modules might be installed or updated.
Define the parameters:
$adminUser = "admin_user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
$mailboxAddress = "shared_mailbox@domain.com"

Install and load the required modules:
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

Connect, it will ask for the corresponding authentication:
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $adminUser

Retrieve the path of the calendar for this account. In english, it is \calendar, but it might be different due to e.g. a different language
$folderPath = (Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $mailboxAddress | Where {$_.Foldertype -eq "Calendar"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FolderPath).Replace("/","\")

Get current settings:
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "${mailboxAddress}:${folderPath}"

Result:
FolderName           User                 AccessRights                           SharingPermissionFlags
----------           ----                 ------------                           ----------------------
Calendar             Default              {AvailabilityOnly}
Calendar             Anonymous            {None}

Change default setting:
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "${mailboxAddress}:${folderPath}" -user "Default" -AccessRights LimitedDetails -SendNotificationToUser $false

Check the change:
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "${mailboxAddress}:${folderPath}"

Result:
FolderName           User                 AccessRights                           SharingPermissionFlags
----------           ----                 ------------                           ----------------------
Calendar             Default              {LimitedDetails}
Calendar             Anonymous            {None}

